# Amazon Linux AMI questions

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a few question regarding the Amazon Linux AMI,

I want to run a local copy of it in vmware is possible to download the image once its laucnhed in amazon and put it into vmware fusion 4 ?

Is it possible to download the amazon linux ami ?

If it isn't possible to download it for local use whats the nearest publicly available os ?

Answer (score 1):

the AMI image cannot be downloaded.

All you can do is, that Depending upon the OS you have, you have to take IMAGE of server, download that Server/HDD image, and run it in your VMware.

for linux, you can use mondorescue

for windows, you can use Acronis True image (which supports conversion of Image files to vmware as well)